# Android studio java with firebase firestore trying to use the new increment

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I got a problem when trying to use the new increment for the cloud firestore
this is my dependency now

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:17.1.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'}
```

I understood that I need firestore version from 21 and above but when I changed it manually
my app crashes
I'm using gradle version 6.0
this is the code that include the increment with the 17.1.2 it can't be recognize and paint in red

```
milk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            DocumentReference documentReference = fstore.collection("users").document(userId);
            documentReference.update("items", FieldValue.increment(1));
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldValue.increment()` is added in Cloud Firestore **v18.2.0**. So you have to change your Firestore version from `17.1.2` to `18.2.0` to use this feature.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.2.0'
```

Comment: @נתן שלו, hit the upvote as well so that others can find it helpful. Thanks